# Get available options from shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to get the available options for a shiny widget (ie. all of the possible checkboxes from a checkboxInput)?

I have some checkbox input where the options available to check are dependent on other input -- they are updated by observers.  Then, suppose I want a button that the user can click and the all of the currently available checkboxes will be checked.

Here is an illustrative example, where I try to update the checkboxes using `updateCheckboxGroupInput` and the variable `input$options`.  However, this doesn't work because `input$options` is only the currently selected boxes, so the button does nothing.

Is there already variable that contains all the available checkboxes, or is necessary to maintain another reactive variable with this information?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            uiOutput('ui')
        )
    ),

    shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
        output$ui <- renderUI({
            inputPanel(
                checkboxGroupInput('options', 'Current Options:',
                                   choices=letters, selected='a', inline=TRUE),
                column(width = 2,
                    actionButton('subset', 'Subset the options'),
                    actionButton('selectAll', 'Select All'))
            )
        })

        ## Observers for buttons
        observeEvent(input$subset,
                     updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                              inputId='options',
                                              choices=sample(letters, 10),
                                              inline=TRUE)
                     )

        observeEvent(input$selectAll,
                     updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                              inputId='options',
                                              ## *** What do I put here for selected? ***
                                              selected=input$options,
                                              inline=TRUE)
                     )
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple Shiny builtin way to do that. You'd have to either use JavaScript to see what the options are, or store the options in a reactive variable